# I'm trying to modify a shader in Unity, but getting "Shader error in 'Custom/SubspaceLook': unrecognized identifier 'Input' at line 82 (on d3d11)"?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I'd like to state right away I don't work with shaders that often, and the basic one I'm playing with - a force field shader from a thread in Unity's forums, is a much older version. However, the original "almost" does what I want it to.

I would like to modify it to add scrolling effects in order to simulate speed, however strangely I'm getting "unrecognized identifier 'Input'". IN Input is a normal variable.. supposedly, in Unity's shaders. Here is my code thus far:

```
Shader "Custom/SubspaceLook" {

Properties {
   _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,0.5)
   _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
   _UVScale ("UV Scale", Range (0.05, 4)) = 1
   _UVDistortion ("UV Distortion", Range (0.01, 1)) = 0.5
   _Rate ("Oscillation Rate", Range (5, 200)) = 10
   _Rate2 ("Oscillation Rate Difference", Range (1, 3)) = 1.43
   _ZPhase ("Z Phase", Range (0, 3)) = 0.5
   _Scale ("Scale", Range (0.02, 2)) = 0.5
   _Distortion ("Distortion", Range (0, 20)) = 0.4
   _ScrollSpeedX("Scroll X", Range(0, 10)) = 2
   _ScrollSpeedY("Scroll Y", Range(0, 10)) = 3
}

SubShader {

   ZWrite Off
   Tags { "Queue" = "Transparent" }
   Blend One One


   Pass {

        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag
        #pragma fragmentoption ARB_fog_exp2
        #include "UnityCG.cginc"

        float4 _Color;
        sampler2D _MainTex;
        float _Rate;
        float _Rate2;
        float _Scale;
        float _Distortion;
        float _ZPhase;
        float _UVScale;
        float _UVDistortion;
        float _ScrollSpeedX;
        float _ScrollSpeedY;

        struct v2f {
            float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
            float3 uvsin : TEXCOORD0;
            float3 vertsin : TEXCOORD1;
            float2 uv : TEXCOORD2;
       };

       v2f vert (appdata_base v)
       {
           v2f o;
           o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos (v.vertex);

           float s = 1 / _Scale;
           float t = (_Time[0]*_Rate*_Scale) / _Distortion;
           float2 uv = float2(v.vertex.y * 0.3 + (v.vertex.y - v.vertex.z * 
           0.0545), v.vertex.x + (v.vertex.z - v.vertex.x * 0.03165));
           o.vertsin = sin((v.vertex.xyz + t) * s);  
           o.uvsin = sin((float3(uv, t * _ZPhase) + (t* _Rate2)) * s) * 
           _Distortion;
           o.uv = uv;

           return o;
       }

    half4 frag (v2f i) : COLOR
    {
        float3 vert = i.vertsin;
        float3 uv = i.uvsin;
        float mix = 1 + sin((vert.x - uv.x) + (vert.y - uv.y) + (vert.z - 
        uv.z));
        float mix2 = 1 + sin((vert.x + uv.x) - (vert.y + uv.y) - (vert.z + 
    uv.z));

        return half4( tex2D( _MainTex, (i.uv + (float2(mix, mix2) * 
        _UVDistortion)) * _UVScale ) * 1.5 * _Color);  
    }

    void surf(Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o)
    {
        fixed2 scrolledUV = IN.uv_MainTex;

        fixed xScrollValue = _ScrollSpeedX * _Time;
        fixed yScrollValue = _ScrollSpeedY * _Time;

        scrolledUV += fixed2(xScrollValue, yScrollValue);

        half2 c = tex2D(_MainTex, scrolledUV);

        o.Albedo = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex).rbg;
        o.Albedo += c.rbg;

        half rim = 1.0 - saturate(dot(normalize(IN.viewDir), o.Normal));
        o.Emission = _Rimcolor.rgb * pow(rim, _RimPower);
    }

    ENDCG

    }
}
    Fallback "Diffuse"
}
```

My primary change to the original shader has been to add the scrolling values and "surf" to it. I have otherwise not touched the first version, which was written by forestjohnson in 2008.

Comment: Please don't tag your questions with useless tags. You neither need a C++ expert nor a OpenGL expert. Non of these technologies are exposed by Unity.

Comment: Apologies, I was going with what the system suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mix matching Surface Shader code and regular shaders:

```
    #pragma vertex vert
    #pragma fragment frag
```

These are for explicit vertex and pixel shaders, while surf() is the unity Surface shader system.

The error pointed by the compiler is that your shader is lacking the **Input struct** referenced by the **surf()** function, but that's not what you need to look into.

```
  struct Input {
      float2 uv_MainTex;
  };
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-SurfaceShaders.html

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to edit this in order to adjust for regular shaders, or should I look for another solution to the scrolling?

Comment: look for "**Normal Extrusion with Vertex Modifier**" in https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-SurfaceShaderExamples.html, which is also modifying vertex positions. Then try to port the feature to your current scrolling surface shader. Alternatively if the old shader you have is fine, then just add the scrolling in there, since you're not using lighting anyway.

Comment: And do note **this silly problem** http://answers.unity.com/answers/298760/view.html